# Why does this javascript keep saying undefined?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using maxmind's geoip script in order to call out visitors individual city and state name when they arrive on my website. This is what I have done.

I have this in my header:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>
```

Then, right under my `<body>` tag, I have the following:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var country=geoip_country();
var region=geoip_region();
var city=geoip_city();
if(country=="")
    country="US";
if(region=="")
    region="New York";
if(city=="")
    city="New York";
</script>
```

Then, in order to show the visitor's city for example, I put this:

```
<script language="JavaScript">document.write(city);</script>
```

However, when I put the directly above on my website, it says *undefined* wherever the city is supposed to show up. It does this with other javascript I have as well and I'm wondering what I am doing wrong......

Thank you for any insights. :)

Comment: Maybe the js lob is big and document.write is being called before the lib is loaded, try using it when the document is loaded

Comment: It won't help your issue, but *please* get rid of the language attribute ([deprecated in HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#adef-language), [removed from HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/scripting-1.html#the-script-element)), it's *soooo* 1995!. :-)

Comment: What does geoip.js look like to you?

Comment: the geoip lists my city, state, country, etc in there, it looks all correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
var country=geoip_country();
```

When execution of your first script block hits that line it crashes because there is no such function as `geoip_country();`, which means no later lines in that block are executed so the calls to `geoip_city()` and `geoip_region()` don't happen at all.

(But the `city` variable itself still exists because of JavaScript's "hoisting" mechanism, so it can be accessed from the second script block but still has a default value of `undefined`.)

You need to change that line to:

```
var country=geoip_country_name();
```

Or, depending on your need, to:

```
var country=geoip_country_code();
```

With that error corrected the rest of the script should run as you expect, including getting the city.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2kbeg/

Comment: Good call. I didn't think to look inside geoip to confirm the function names. I also just learned that I can't vote my own answer down.

Answer (score 1):

The statement might be executing before the DOM is ready, document.write(city); You can put it in function and call on body load. you can put the script tags in Head or just before the closing body tag.

Instead of using using document.write() you can assign the city to some span or div or any html control.

```
<body onload="myFun();" >........
<div id="city" ></div>


<script language="JavaScript">

function myFun()
{
  // document.write(city);
    document.getElementById('city').innertText = city;
}
</script>
```

Comment: did you make up myFun or what is myFun exactly?

Comment: I just give a name it could by any name you like for your function.

Comment: so i would add this to the head of the page?

Comment: But you don't want to start doing `document.write()` calls _after_ the document is loaded... The problem the OP has is that the statement outputs `undefined` - this is because the variable is not set correctly, not because the DOM isn't ready yet.

Comment: sorry i dont understand javascript that well :(

Comment: No worries, You need to put little effort to learn javascript if you have programming skill. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For linked resources, I think you need to specify the type, instead of the language:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>
```

Edit: As per comment, yes it would be better to write into a designated output area:

```
<div id="OutputDiv">No output yet.</div>
```

You also might want to put your defaults into a `window.onload` function, instead of running immediately:

```
window.onload = function() {
    //Your code here
    var country=geoip_country();
    var region=geoip_region();
    var city=geoip_city();
    if(country=="")
        country="US";
    if(region=="")
        region="New York";
    if(city=="")
        city="New York";

    //document.write(city);
    var outputDiv = document.getElementById('OutputDiv');
    outputDiv.innerHTML = "City is " + city;

};
```

This also lets you be certain that you are running the output after the variable has been set (or is supposed to be).

Comment: i changed it to type, but it didn't change anything. is the "window.onload" function, do you mean make a new js file and put it in there, then load it similarly to the geoip script? and for the order, i added that script right under the body tag, so shouldn't that mean it is loaded before the other data that is below it? (the city tag that is putting the information there is below what you put into that window onload thing above)

Comment: But you don't want to start doing `document.write()` calls _after_ the document is loaded...

Comment: nnnnnn, agreed. Changed answer to include an output div where city can be written to.

Comment: @sab, you can put the `window.onload` function either in a separate js file, or just put the entire function into one of your inline script blocks. The key is that code you want to run will wait until the onload event to fire before executing, instead of trying to run immediately when **not** contained in such a function.

The problem you might have been having before is that your calls to `geoip_city()` etc might have been executing before the browser had loaded the geoip.js resource, so it was not finding the desired function (and so took the `undefined` value).